# $.ajax not a function in yii

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have the below function that I used in two different pages and worked perfectly in both cases. Suddenly my pages stopped updating and I got the error $.ajax not a function.

```
function update_report(data) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "report?poids="+data,
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#yw2").html(msg);            
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });


    req ="a";
}
```

I then changed the $ to jQuery. Then it started sending AJAX requests but it didnt get the relative URL. Like I was generating the request from a page like /index.php/link1 and my code was sending request to /index.php/report rather then /index.php/link1/report

So, then I changed my url: to "link1/report=?"+data then it started sending request to the right page but couldnt update the response as it didnt find the div #id. Got error

TypeError: $(...) is null

What can cause all this issue and how to fix this? And why $.ajax suddenly stopped working, though I didnt make any changes?

Comment: you might have included jquery library twice

Answer (score 0):

JQuery can be not available by `$.ajax()`. Check if `jQuery.ajax()` is available or you included jquery twice.

You should not require jquery manually. The best way to include jquery is using `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery')`. Path for library is set in `config/main.php`.

Comment: I mentioned already that I tried changing $ into jQuery. Then I started having issue with relative URL. I didnt add jQuery manually it was added by default. Now, my page is working fine as I changed both $ to jQuery and changed the URL aswell. But, I want to figure out what caused the issue, as I mentioned the code was working perfectly and it stsrted giving error suddenly while I made no changes in the jquery source or config. In my page source I can see jquery.js is included once and there are other js files like jquery.knob.js included from the template. Are they conflicting ?